# facing issue for using oracle11g instead of oracle 10g?

Tags: vb.net, oracle11g, oracle10g

In past we devloped vb.net application using oracle 10g,now i updated oracle10g  to oracle11g .(**my pc configuration is 64bit windows 8.2 and oracle11g** ).(we tried 11g 32bit as well as 64 bit, both does not worked out). now i try to run my application i got this error "
 Unable to load DLL '**OraOps10.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)**" . In my oracle installed bin folder does not contain OraOps10.dll, instead of contain OraOps11w.dll. i known because of version changed i am facing this error .At the same time in my application bin folder i have changed  oracle.DataAccess.dll for oracle 11 g version. after that i m not getting '**OraOps10.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)**"  error. But i am facing another oracle connection issue. any suggestion please ?

Comment: What code loads the DLL?

Answer (score 0):

Open a Visual Studio command prompt as follows: Click Start, point to All Programs, point to Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, point to Tools, and then click Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010).
At the command prompt, type the following command:
gacutil /u 
In this command, assembly name is the name of the assembly to uninstall from the GAC.
The following example removes an assembly named hello.dll from the GAC.
gacutil /u "hello,Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0123456789ABCDEF"